# C++ pointer offset gets squared

Tags: c++, pointers, offset

I have a data type called 'tod', with which I create arrays.  To iterate between elements of this type inside function (with pointer), I want to use an offset.  However, this offset gets squared during operation:

```
tod theTime[] = { {12,0,0, "noon"}, {0,0,0, "midnight"}, {11,30,0, "lunch time"}, {18,45,0, "supper time"}, {23,59,59, "bed time"} };
auto tsize = sizeof(tod);
auto p1 = &theTime[0];
auto p2 = &theTime[0] + tsize;
cout << "size of tod = " << tsize << endl;
cout << "p1 = " << p1 << endl;
cout << "p2 = " << p2 << endl;
```

That gives me:

```
size of tod = 44
p1 = 0x7ffd3e3b0bf0
p2 = 0x7ffd3e3b1380
```

The difference between the two hex values comes down to 0x790, which is 1936 (decimal) and 44^2.  How is this happening?  Someone please help.

Comment: Adding an integer to a pointer means to advance by that number of units of the thing being pointed to  (not that number of bytes as you seem to assume).  `&theTime[0] + 1` would give you `&theTime[1]`; you may have heard that `a[b]` is equivalent to `*(a+b)`

Comment: `tsize = sizeof(tod) = 44`.. therefore sizeof each element in `theTime` is 44.. thus.. `&arr[0] + 44` is actually the same as `addressof(arr) + (tsize * sizeof(eachElement))`.

Since sizeof each element is 44 and you are asking to go to the 44'th element, you get `44 * 44`. Your array doesn't contain that many elements so undefined behaviour.

Comment: I really have to wonder how this comes to be. Does not every tutorial, textbook, and primer about pointers in C or C++ clearly state they operate in units of the objects they point to, not bytes? How can somebody learn about pointers without learning this?

Comment: @EricPostpischil sadly there's a fair amount of tutorials that say "pointers are integers"

Comment: @M.M, that is indeed the misconception I had.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're misunderstanding about [pointer arithmetic](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_arithmetic#Additive_operators):

> If the pointer P points to the ith element of an array, then the expressions P+n, n+P, and P-n are pointers of the same type that point to the i+nth, i+nth, and i-nth element of the same array, respectively.

e.g. `&theTime[0] + 1` will return the pointer pointing to the 2nd element of the array `theTime`; then `&theTime[0] + tsize` will try to return the pointer pointing to the `tsize + 1`th element (note it's getting out of the bound and leads to UB). That's why you got `1936`, i.e. `44 * 44`.

Comment: Thank you, sir.  You saved my life.